# Countdown timer with arc canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have created a countdown timer with `canvas`. It's working well, but there are some problems:

I need to relative circle seconds with circle minutes and hours and days like [this demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Slick-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Plugin-Classy-Countdown/).

Please run the code snippet in a full page.

Please, do not suggest to use plugins, because I'd like to write short code and also I'd like to know more and more about jQuery & JavaScript.

```js
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.countdown = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = {
            'date': null
        };
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        this_sel = $(this);

        /*Canvas Variables*/
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 70;
        var kk = 0;
        /*End Canvas Variables*/

        function count_exec() {
            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
            if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60;

            context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            kk = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10471));

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + kk, false);
            context.lineWidth = 8;
            context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            context.stroke();

            // Add 0 value to left of value
            if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
                this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
                this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
                this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
            }
        }
        // #region Execute Interval
         count_exec();
        interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);
        // #endregion

    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "6 january 2017 7:15:00"
    },
      function () {
          $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
      }
    );

})
```

```css
#countdown .countdown-container{
                width:25%;
                position:relative;
                float:left;
                border:1px solid #0fd562;
            }
            #countdown .countdown-container >div{
                position:absolute;
                top:100px;
                left:95px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .secs, span{
                font-size:16px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">
    <div class="countdown-container">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="secs">
                00
            </div>
            <span>Seconds</span>
        </div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-container">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="mins">
                00
            </div>
            <span>Minutes</span>
        </div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-container">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="hours">
                00
            </div>
            <span>Hours</span>
        </div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-container">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="days">
                00
            </div>
            <span>Days</span>
        </div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put different id to each canvas, in hours and days you have the same as in seconds.

After this you need to execute the function with the different parameters necessary to draw each canvas, not only for canvas (
Better if you create a function that receives a canvas and runs its painted. I did everything in the same function for time)

```js
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.countdown = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = {
            'date': null
        };
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        this_sel = $(this);
        /*Canvas Variables*/

        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 70;
        var kk = 0;
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
        var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
        var centerX2 = canvas2.width / 2;
        var centerY2 = canvas2.height / 2;
        var radius2 = 70;
        var kk2 = 0;
        var canvas3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
        var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
        var centerX3 = canvas3.width / 2;
        var centerY3 = canvas3.height / 2;
        var radius3 = 70;
        var kk3 = 0;
        var canvas4 = document.getElementById('myCanvas4');
        var context4 = canvas4.getContext('2d');
        var centerX4 = canvas4.width / 2;
        var centerY4 = canvas4.height / 2;
        var radius4 = 70;
        var kk4 = 0;
        /*End Canvas Variables*/
        function count_exec() {
            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
            if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60;


            context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            kk = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.1046));
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + kk, false);
            context.lineWidth = 8;
            context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            context.stroke();
            
            context2.clearRect(50, 50, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
            kk2 = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.1046));
            context2.beginPath();
            context2.arc(centerX2, centerY2, radius2, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + kk2, false);
            context2.lineWidth = 8;
            context2.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            context2.stroke();
            
            context3.clearRect(50, 50, canvas3.width, canvas3.height);
            kk3 = ((24 - hours) * parseFloat(0.261));
            context3.beginPath();
            context3.arc(centerX3, centerY3, radius3, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + kk3, false);
            context3.lineWidth = 8;
            context3.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            context3.stroke();
           
            context4.clearRect(50, 50, canvas4.width, canvas4.height);
            kk4 = ((365 - days) * parseFloat(0.0172));
            context4.beginPath();
            context4.arc(centerX4, centerY4, radius4, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + kk4, false);
            context4.lineWidth = 8;
            context4.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            context4.stroke();
            // add 0 value to left of value
            if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
                this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
                this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
                this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
            }
        }
        // #region Execute Interval
         count_exec();
        interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);
        // #endregion
       
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "6 january 2017 7:15:00"
    },
      function () {
          $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
      }
    );

})
```

```css
#countdown .countdown-container{
                width:25%;
                position:relative;
                float:left;
                border:1px solid #0fd562;
            }
            #countdown .countdown-container >div{
                position:absolute;
                top:100px;
                left:95px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .secs, span{
                font-size:16px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="secs">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Seconds</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="mins">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Minutes</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="hours">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Hours</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="days">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Days</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas4" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I put days in 365 format 2PI/365=0,0172, maybe you you want to change to week or month.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```js
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.countdown = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = {
            'date': null
        };
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        this_sel = $(this);
        /*Canvas Variables*/
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        
        /*Min Canvas*/
        var canvasMin = document.getElementById('canvasMin');
        var contextMin = canvasMin.getContext('2d');
        var centerMinX = canvasMin.width / 2;
        var centerMinY = canvasMin.height / 2;
        
        /*Hour Canvas*/
        var canvasHour = document.getElementById('canvasHours');
        var contextHour = canvasHour.getContext('2d');
        var centerHourX = canvasHour.width / 2;
        var centerHourY = canvasHour.height / 2;
        
        /*Day Canvas*/
        var canvasDays = document.getElementById('canvasDays');
        var contextDays = canvasDays.getContext('2d');
        var centerDaysX = canvasDays.width / 2;
        var centerDaysY = canvasDays.height / 2;
        
        var radius = 70;
        var kk = 0;
        var min = 0;

        /*End Canvas Variables*/
        function count_exec() {
            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
            if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60;


            context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            kk = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10471));

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + kk, false);
            context.lineWidth = 8;
            context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            context.stroke();
            
            // MInutes arc
            contextMin.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            min = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.10471));

            contextMin.beginPath();
            contextMin.arc(centerMinX, centerMinY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + min, false);
            contextMin.lineWidth = 8;
            contextMin.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            contextMin.stroke();
            
            // Hours arc
            contextHour.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            hour = ((60 - hours) * parseFloat(0.10471));

            contextHour.beginPath();
            contextHour.arc(centerMinX, centerMinY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour, false);
            contextHour.lineWidth = 8;
            contextHour.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            contextHour.stroke();
            
            // Days arc
            contextDays.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            day = ((60 - days) * parseFloat(0.10471));

            contextDays.beginPath();
            contextDays.arc(centerMinX, centerMinY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + day, false);
            contextDays.lineWidth = 8;
            contextDays.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
            contextDays.stroke();
            
            // add 0 value to left of value
            if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            //console.log(days+' : '+hours+' : '+minutes+' : '+seconds);
                this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
                this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
                this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
                this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
            }
        }
        // #region Execute Interval
         count_exec();
        interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);
        // #endregion
       
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "8 january 2017 00:00:00"
    },
      function () {
          $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
      }
    );

})
```

```css
#countdown .countdown-container{
                width:25%;
                position:relative;
                float:left;
                border:1px solid #0fd562;
            }
            #countdown .countdown-container >div{
                position:absolute;
                top:100px;
                left:95px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .secs, span{
                font-size:16px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="secs">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Seconds</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="mins">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Minutes</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="canvasMin" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="hours">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Hours</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="canvasHours" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="days">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Days</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="canvasDays" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```